# Click button automatically in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I created an app with Webview and need to press button automatically

Use case:- open link [web link](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/home)
and want to press "Login Here" button automatically (Second button at right).

I tried Using this:-

Html from website for "Login Here" button was `<input _ngcontent-c13="" style="padding: 2px" type="button" class="pri_btn" value="Login Here">`
It does not have **id** or **name** so i tried with class name but nothing happened

```
String js = "javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementByClassName('pri_btn');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()";
    webView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            String result = s;

        }
    });
```

which return null.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Just use [this][1] link in your webView instead


  [1]: https://portal.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/UserLogin/LoginHome.html?lang=eng

Comment: @RoyalGriffin it redirects to the same link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to use a method called `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural) which returns **array** of elements. So your code should look like this:

```
String js = "javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementsByClassName('pri_btn')[0];"+
    "l.click();"+
    "})()";
webView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        String result = s;
    }
});
```

Also, when I tried running this function, an SSL error occured during the redirect. To fix this you should override `onReceivedSslError()` method in your `WebViewClient`, like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        if (handler != null){
            handler.proceed();
        } else {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
        }
    }
});

webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

---

Edit:
Checking for "login" occurence in the elements' value:

```
javascript:(function(){
tab = document.getElementsByClassName('pri_btn');
for(var i=0; i< tab.length; i++){
    if(tab[i].value.toLowerCase().indexOf("login") !== -1) return tab[i].click();
}
})()
```

Comment: i  need to check the value of element too so that I can check it clicked only "login" element. As we don't know when the developer can add a new button with same class on 0 index

Answer (score 0):

there is no method called **getElementByClassName**. It should be `getElementsByClassName`. Also **getElementsByClassName** returns an array not a DOM element. So you can't use variable **l** as an element.

Try This:

```
var loginBtns=document.getElementByClassName('pri_btn');
//assuming that there is only one element with class name pri_btn
loginBtns[0].click();
```